# Ensure changes in a data aware control get captured on form close

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I've noticed that if a form with data aware controls is **closed from the title bar** and the active control has had its data changed that change never makes it into the underlying data source. I've traced this to the CM_EXIT message never getting fired for the control.

How can I ensure that no matter which control last had focus these changes get pushed to the data source?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could send the needed CM_Exit in the OnCloseQuery event of your form.

```
procedure TMyForm.FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);
begin
  if Assigned(ActiveControl) then
    SendMessage(ActiveControl.Handle, CM_EXIT,0,0);
end;
```

Answer (score 4):

I usually handle this by testing all data set components. If they're in the `Modified` state, then I simply call `Post` on them.

You can do this in the `OnCloseQuery` for the form.

Comment: This was already being done. Most DB aware controls update the dataset when they lose focus but in this case the focus was never lost so the change never propagates to the dataset.

Comment: @KennethCochran, by updated, I think you mean they `Post` the updates when they lose focus. They "modify" the dataset as soon as you make a change if you have AutoEdit enabled, which I presume you do. There's no magic here. It's the same as if you called `Edit`, made a change, and didn't `Post`. You simply need to call `Post` to commit the changes.

Comment: By the way, I like bummi's answer. It's simple and elegant, but this is the less hacky way to do it. This is also the cross-platform way to do it. There's no Windows messaging system on the Mac.

Answer (score 0):

On your `OnClose` event handler just add the line below:

```
Perform(WM_NEXTDLGCTL, 0, 0);
```

It will make the focus go to the next component in the `TabOrder` and, by removing the focus from the current component, will send the value to the field.

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI. A cross platform way of forcing the control to exit is:

```
SelectNext(ActiveControl, True, True);
```

This will work for any control that has at lease one other sibling in the same parent container.

Answer (score 0):

I think the right way is to call `UpdateRecord` on the underlying dataset components (e.g. in `OnCloseQuery`). This will update the data from the controls.

If you call `Post` instead, this will internally call `UpdateRecord` as well. This is why [Marcus' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18927487/2306907) will work too.